# Two dimensional array - sorting numbers in rows

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Why doesn't sorting numbers in each row separately work?

It works only for the last row, and I don't know why.

```js
function sortowanie(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}
var tab = new Array(20);
var tabS = new Array(5);
var sumaS = new Array(5);
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    tab[i] = new Array(5);
    tabS[i] = 0
}
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j<5; j++) {
        tab[i, j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*90) + 10;
        document.write("["+tab[i, j]+"]"+" "); 
        sumaS[j] = tab[i, j];    
    } 
    tabS[i] = sumaS.sort(sortowanie);    
    document.write("<br>");
}   
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    document.write(tabS[i] + "<br>");
}
```

I expect for example:

```
1 12 45 55 76<br>
0 43 76 88 92<br>
```

.. and so on

Comment: `tab[i, j]` does not do what you think. You mean `tab[i][j]`.

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks for that. Im gonna edit my post. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `tab[i, j]` should really be `tab[i][j]`
- You mutate the `summaS` array in every iteration of the `i` loop, so you actually assign the *same* array again and again to the result. Modifications *after* having assigned it to `tabS[i]` will still be visible in `tabS[i]`, so in the end you see the same array multiple times.

Fix it by moving the initialisation of the `summaS` array inside the outer loop:

```js
function sortowanie(a, b) {
    return a-b;
}
var tab = new Array(20);
var tabS = new Array(5);
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    tab[i] = new Array(5);
    tabS[i] = 0
}
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    var sumaS = new Array(5);
    for(var j = 0; j<5; j++) {
        tab[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*90) + 10;
        document.write("["+tab[i][j]+"]"+" "); 
        sumaS[j] = tab[i][j];    
    } 
    tabS[i] = sumaS.sort(sortowanie);    
    document.write("<br>");
}   
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    document.write(tabS[i] + "<br>");
}
```